# Alias model attributes API Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I´m building an API in Lumen that has input and output of data (get, post, etc...). I would like to mask my model attributes (database column names) through the API responses and incoming requests in order to not expose database column names.

For responses I have made transformations, but when requests comes for data posting, is more difficult because I have to change input names (to the real column names) so the model manipulation functions works.

Is there a Laravel/Lumen feature or package that could handle this in a way of map column names like

```
$columnMap = [
         'real_model_attribute' => 'api_exposed_attribute_name',
         ...
         ...
];
```

Thanks!